# How to Integrate Aptana studio with Bitnami Ruby Stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana3

Hi Every one I have installed [Apana Studion 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html) and [Binami Ruby Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby)

I am unable to integrate these two. I want aptana to use the bitnamei ruby stack in aptana .
I have a ruby application i am unable to import it and run it.

I am new to ruby on rails . Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. There isn't an integration.
Just set the workspace for aptana to the projects folder and don't use the terminal on aptana studio Just use the use_ruby.bat for terminal commands.

I know senseless to actually have an IDE as nothing but a text editor but trust me you start integrating crap up the dependancy issues will ruin your life.